# Is G-ddamn considered cursing God?

Tags: words, sin

If a person says in English the word g-ddamn (or G-d damn) does that transgress the sin of cursing God?

Comment: Are you specifically interested in cursing, or also about other ways this could be a sin?  (The plain meaning of the phrase *seems* to be that you're asking God to perform that action, not applying it *to* God.)

Comment: @MonicaCellio I have seen Christians explain that the word is blasphemy, not taking the "The Lord's" name in vein. From what I can tell various dictionaries seem to indicate that it is just used for emphasis, not necessarily having a meaning of its own.

Comment: Related: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/18222/source-for-the-prohibition-against-nivul-peh-foul-mouth

Comment: My impression is that when someone is upset at a thing, they say "GD [thing]". They're not cursing god, rather they're asking for god to curse the thing that they're upset about. However my understanding of the English may be overly literal.

Comment: No. This is not part of Ten Commandments, ppl cannot curse since ppl do not have powers to do so.

Answer (score 13):

No, it does not.

"Cursing" someone in a Biblical sense means saying "may G-d strike you." Thus a person would only be liable for cursing their parent if they said "may G-d strike you" to their parent.

When someone says "*I hit my thumb with this G-ddamn hammer!*", an English professor would tell you that means "may G-d damn this hammer because I am mad at it." In effect you are cursing the hammer. It may be a wasted use of G-d's name, but it's not "blasphemy" per se. (Many people today might actually intend "this G-ddamned hammer", i.e. "I assume G-d has already cursed this hammer", which means you're not cursing anything with your statement. Just like calling something "G-dforsaken.")

The Talmud ([Sanhedrin 56a](http://www.mechon-mamre.org/b/l/l4407.htm)) explains that the only form of true "blasphemy", as described in [Leviticus 24:15](http://bible.ort.org/books/pentd2.asp?ACTION=displaypage&BOOK=3&CHAPTER=24#C2665), would then be to curse G-d in a biblical sense, i.e. to say "may Joe strike Joe" (or "may Joe damn Joe", for that matter), substituting "G-d" for Joe. (Which is a bit strange, if someone doesn't believe in G-d, why they're calling on Him to smite anything, but never mind.) Maimonides, [Laws of Foreign Worship 2:7](http://www.mechon-mamre.org/i/1402.htm) discusses the severity of punishment may depend on exactly which name of G-d is used, but in conclusion:

- "*G-ddamn it*", "this *G-ddamn hammer*", and the like are wasteful uses of G-d's name and should be avoided, but are not "cursing G-d" or "blasphemy."
- Do not direct a "*G-ddamn you*" towards any person; especially not towards your parent; and definitely not towards G-d.

Comment: why do you use the term "should be avoided"? Isn't it a transgression of the Second Commandment?

Comment: @Menachem you mean the Third, no? That wasn't the scope of the question, and we'd get into a discussion of how it applies to translated names of G-d. So I left it at just "don't."

Comment: I did mean the third