# What are the implications of "deserving death"?

Tags: sin, capital-punishment

The Sources frequently say that certain people "deserve death".  Examples in the Talmud:

> He who transgresses the rulings of the Sages deserve death. [Berakhot 4b]
>
> He who emits semen in vain deserves death. [Niddah 13a]
>
> A Sage with a fat stain on his clothes deserves death. [Shabbat 114a]
>
> He who does not study [the Torah] deserves death.  [Pirkei Avot 1:13]
>
> A gentile who observes Shabbat deserves death. [Sanhedrin 58b]

I know this is just an expression of disapproval and that the death in question would have to come from heaven.  (Execution is only for specific infractions listed in the Torah with extremely rare exceptions.)

But are there penalties for being declared as "deserving death"?  Flogging, fines, shunning?  Is a process of teshuvah (repentence) required, or should one just stop doing what's wrong without further ado?

Comment: Highly relevant answer: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/20441